# Connes' long exact sequence in cyclic homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, k-theory

I'm working on the book Cyclic Homology by Loday ([https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~vallette/GdT/Cyclic%20Homology%20-%20Loday.pdf](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Evallette/GdT/Cyclic%20Homology%20-%20Loday.pdf)) and in the section 2.2, he constructs the Connes' long exact sequence (Theorem 2.2.1) and he says that the connecting morphism is the morphism B in 2.1.7 but I can't see why. Does someone see why ?

And to be sure that I well understood, in the exact sequence of bicomplexes which gives this long exact sequence, the morphism between CC(A) and CC(A)[2,0] is the natural one who sends $A^{⊗q+1}$ on itself if p is greater than 3 and 0 otherwise ?

Thank you

Comment: It feels like Loday is being a bit sloppy here. I think in the case where $A$ is unital, Remark 2.2.2 together with the homotopy formula $bB + Bb = 0$ can give the necessary insight, since connecting homomorphisms can often be constructed explicitly through diagram chasing when such homotopies are available. When $A$ is not unital, it is unclear how to even define $B$, since his definition of $B$ explicitly uses the unit. In the non-unital case, I would interpret this long exact sequence as the definition of $B$ as a map on cohomology, not stemming from an explicit map on cochains.

Comment: I think that you are right, I did the computation by a diagram chasing for the unital case and it gives the morphism $B$ composed with a projection. Thank you.